# How to create an element not just place it on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I need to create an instance of the element `Grid` so that I can call functions on it in the code? For example, if `theGrid` is of type `Grid`, I want to both place it on the page, but I also want to save it as a local variable so I can later say: `theGrid.forceUpdate()`.

The code below doesn't display a `Grid`. But if I replace with `<Grid...>` where `theGrid` is (with parameters of course), it does show on the page, but I no longer can reference it in my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid } from 'react-virtualized';
import ReactInterval from 'react-interval';

// Grid data as an array of arrays
const quoteList = [
  ['GE', 100, 35.28, 35.30, 100, 95125],
  ['IBM', 100, 135.11, 135.20, 100, 195125],
  ['C', 100, 45.23, 45.30, 100, 195125]
];

const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      enabled: false,
      timeout: 1000,
      count: 0
    };
  },

  cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
    return (
      <div
        key={key}
        style={style}
      >
        {quoteList[rowIndex][columnIndex]}
      </div>
    )  
  },

  render() {
    const {timeout, enabled, count} = this.state;
    var theGrid = React.createElement(Grid, {
          cellRenderer:this.cellRenderer,
          columnCount:quoteList[0].length,
          columnWidth:50,
          height:quoteList.length * 20,
          rowCount:quoteList.length,
          isVisible : true,
          rowHeight:20,
          width:800}, null);

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactInterval {...{timeout, enabled}}
          callback={
            () => {
              this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
              quoteList[0][1] = this.state.count
              console.log(quoteList[0][1])
            }
          } 
        />

        <input type="number" step="200" min="200" max="5000" value={this.state.timeout}
          onChange={({target: {value}}) => this.setState({timeout: parseInt(value, 10)})} />&nbsp;

        <button disabled={enabled} onClick={() => this.setState({enabled: true})}>
          Start</button>&nbsp;

        <button disabled={!enabled} onClick={() => this.setState({enabled: false})}>
          Stop</button>&nbsp;

        {count}

        <div>
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <theGrid/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

const appRoot = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(appRoot);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, appRoot);
```

Comment: "theGrid is of type Grid" -- what does that mean?  Also, are you trying to work with it from within the app or from elsewhere?

Comment: Grid has functions that can be called, for example, forceUpdate. How do you suggest that say there is a button on the screen that when clicked, I want to call Grid.forceUpdate()  from the callback function of the button's click method?

Comment: For now I want to just call it from within App.

Comment: I suspect I have to call React.CreateElement(Grid) or something like that, then place it on the code the way I do Grid.

Comment: Probably not that.  It depends on the structure of your app and whether or not you are using Redux.  Publish the call site for Grid.

Comment: I put the whole code in the post. I thought this is an elementary question but I guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using refs?

Add this prop to your `Grid`:

```
ref={(ref) => this.theGrid = ref}
```

Now you should be able to reference the grid via `this.theGrid`.

The author of react-virtual addressing a similar issue:

https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/383

More on refs:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Comment: Well the problem is that when I use  <theGrid/>, it doesn't show a Grid. When I pass  <Grid with parameters />it does. So I either get to access it because I have a variable around but it doesn't show, or I can show it, but I can't access it.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your answer though. Maybe a more complete section of code would help.